# Получение значение литерала (константы) средствами CIL

Tags: .net, const, cil

Скажем, у нас есть некая константа в откомпилированной сборке. Возьмем примера ради класс [Math](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math?view=netframework-4.7.2) из `mscorlib.dll` и константу [Math.PI](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.math.pi?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

Если посмотреть исходник в виде `IL`-кода, то мы увидим такое вот объявление поля:

```
.field public static literal float64 PI = float64(3.1415926535897931)
```

То есть по сути, `PI` является публичным статическим полем, помеченным как литерал
И именно из-за последнего не будет работать инструкция `ldsfld` в отношении `Math.PI`

Из-за чего следующий код не будет работоспособным:

```
.method public static float64 GetPi() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 1
    ldsfld float64 [mscorlib]System.Math::PI
    ret
}
```

При вызове `GetPi()` мы получим ошибку времени исполнения:

> System.MissingFieldException: "Поле не найдено: "System.Math.PI"."

В связи с чем у меня и возник вопрос: **можно ли** вообще средствами `CIL` вытащить значение литерала из сборки и, если *да*, то **как** это сделать?

---

P.S. - я прекрасно понимаю, что при создании `IL`-кода из инструкций на, скажем, `C#` значения констант подставляются сразу, так что сие:

```
return a * Math.PI;
```

будет преобразовано в:

```
ldloc a
ldc.r8 3.1415926535897931
mul
ret
```

Однако все таки стало интересно, есть ли в `CIL` инструкция, которая все таки извлекала бы значение константного поля

Comment: [похоже что нет](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27115482/2881286)

Comment: @Grundy, может, оформите ответ?)

Comment: Надо получше вникнуть, потому что [вот с рефлексией](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10261824/2881286) вроде как должно работать, но не пробовал еще. Плюс тому ответу 4 года уже, может что-нибудь поменялось

Comment: @Grundy, рефлексия-то работать будет. Только надо бы глянуть, как она устроена. Ибо, по логике вещей, вся рефлексия так же представлена IL-кодом ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Не все в .NET представлено IL-кодом. Часть методов реализована в виде машинного кода в составе CLR (написанного на С++), в исходниках .NET это выражается как объявление метода с флагом MethodImplOptions.InternalCall (например: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtimehandles.cs,2cc6d09727d9d742)

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, это да, я знаю. Только мне почему-то запомнилось из исходников, что у методов `GetField(...)` в `Type` есть какая-то нативная реализация ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Однако, ошибся)

Comment: По видимому, ключевую роль в получении значения поля играет вот этот метод: [MetadataImport._GetDefaultValue](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/mdimport.cs,3da2fe43b3391b70,references)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В спецификации [CIL](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf) достаточно четко указано:

> **I.8.6.1.2 Location signatures**
>
> The **literal constraint** promises that the value of the location is actually a fixed value of a built-in type. The value is specified as part of the constraint. Compilers are
> required to replace all references to the location with its value, and the VES therefore
> need not allocate space for the location. This constraint, while logically applicable to
> any location, shall only be placed on static fields of compound types. ***Fields that are
> so marked are not permitted to be referenced from CIL*** (they shall be in-lined to their
> constant value at compile time), but are available using reflection and tools that
> directly deal with the metadata.

Выделенный кусок

> ***Fields that are so marked are not permitted to be referenced from CIL***

> Поля отмеченные таким способом не могут быть доступны из CIL

Так что нет, такой инструкции в CIL нет.

Однако, как указано в том же пункте:

> but are available using reflection and tools that
> directly deal with the metadata.

> но доступны при использовании рефлексии или инструментов работающих напрямую с метаданными.

<sub>перевод ответа на вопрос [CIL - How do I use a public static literal field?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27115482/2881286)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Дополню [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/888462/248572) [@Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy):

Как уже было сказано, штатными средствами `CIL` получить значение литерала **нельзя**, так что следует использовать [рефлексию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))

Собственно, этим и займемся)
Получился такой вот `generic`-метод:

```
.method public static !!ConstType GetConst<ConstType>(class [mscorlib]System.Type, string) cil managed 
{
    .maxstack 3
    ldarg.0     // Кладем на стек тип, из которого будем тащить константу
    ldarg.1     // Кладем на стек название литерала
    ldc.i4 56   // Кладем на стек значение BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic
                // т.к. константа всегда является полем статичным и не совсем обязательно публичным)

    // Достанем FieldInfo
    callvirt instance class [mscorlib]System.Reflection.FieldInfo [mscorlib]System.Type::GetField(string, valuetype [mscorlib]System.Reflection.BindingFlags)
    ldnull

    // Получим его значение
    callvirt instance object [mscorlib]System.Reflection.FieldInfo::GetValue(object)

    // Распакуем
    unbox.any !!ConstType

    // Вернем
    ret
}
```

Тогда метод `GetPi()` можно переписать так:

```
.method public static float64 GetPi() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 2
    // Получим тип класса System.Math
    ldtoken [mscorlib]System.Math
    call class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeTypeHandle)

    // Укажем, какую константу хотим из него вытащить
    ldstr "PI"

    // И, собственно, вытащим)
    call !!0 ILConsole.Program::GetConst<float64>(class [mscorlib]System.Type, string)
    ret
}
```

Теперь вызов метода не упадет в `runtime`, а вернет ожидаемое значение `System.Math.PI`)

---

Еще раз подчеркну, что *константы на то и константы*, что их неизменяемое значение подставляется сразу в `IL`-код, так что при написании какого-нибудь компилятора не стоит использовать код выше, а следует просто вручную записать нужную величину куда следует

Данный ответ приведен только в, так скажем, *образовательных* целях)

Comment: Интересно, а нельзя ли через ldtoken загрузить сразу токен константы? Хоть и написано что на константу нельзя ссылаться через CIL, но токен же все-таки не значение...

Comment: @PavelMayorov: таки нельзя) Такая конструкция: `ldtoken [mscorlib]System.Math::PI` не является допустимой, а при точечной нотации `System.Math.PI` воспринимается как класс)